# Removing specific node in XML

Tags: qt4

I have created XML file  using QXmlStreamWriter .
How can i delete one node based on some key value .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the wrong API you're using there. `QXmlStreamWriter`, as the name says, writes a stream of XML data. Once you're done writing, you end up with an XML file, which must be parsed back if you want to modify it.

If you plan to regularly modify your XML file, consider using `QDomDocument`. The `QXmlStream...` classes are used for serializing and de-serializing of data structures, not quite for editing of XML documents.

Another idea is to use an XSLT processor.

Comment: Can you please give a small example ?
Thanks in adv .

Comment: Your question is a bit lacking there. I don't exactly know what "some key value" is. I recommend in any case that you look at the `QDomDocument` documentation; it contains some examples.